# What is the meaning of picture of hand with Arabic word in a Ta`weez

Tags: tawiz

While cleaning the top roof of my room I have discovered a strange thing. A silver color beautifully decorated large taweez. Out of curiosity I have opened it and found 3 pieces of paper with drawing and many Arabic sentences. A beautiful smell was emitting from it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know Arabic. I just want to know what is the purpose of this taweez? How It comes to my roof top?

Comment: Taweez making is an esoteric and obscure practice and for the most part is not grounded in authentic Islamic sources. I don't think anyone will be able to tell you the intended purpose.

Comment: Probably ask your parents, or elders that who and why have put it there... One thing to notice Hazrat Ali is in center and not Prophet Mohammad's meaning it's written by ahle tashi. and fingers have all 12 imams of ahle tashi. But also strange to notice the name of Abu bakar near thumb... (which makes it so *un* ahle tashi...). Also tavaiz haiving numbers are only superstitions that people think that they protect them, there is no such footing for it in Islam. If you put these and commit sins, then God will get you anyway here or hereafter  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first picture is an explanation of 5 virtuous people in the Islam: **The Prophet Muhammad** (pbuh), **Hazrat Ali Amir-Al-Mo'menin** (pbuh), daughter of The Prophet **Fatemeh Al-Zahra** (S.A.), and two of their children **Imam Hasan-ibn-Ali** and **Imam Hussain-ibn-Ali**- Peace be on All of Them.

These five holy people are referred to them as [Ahl al-Kisa' (or the People of the Cloak).](http://en.wikishia.net/view/Hadith_al-Kisa%27)

In the center of the palm, holy name of Amir-Al-Mo'menin **ALI** (S.A.) has been drawn in a circle. Four surrounding semicircle illustrated with holy statements:

> لااله الا الله الواحد القهار
>
> لا اله الا الله الکریم الغفار
>
> لا اله الا الله العزیز الستار
>
> and something else similar to these, I couldn't read

Each phalanx contains names of [12 Shia Imams.](http://en.wikishia.net/view/Imamate)

Around the hand, there is a beautiful poem by major Persian poet:

> بلغ العلی بکماله
>
> کشف الدجی بجماله
>
> حسنت جمیع خصاله
>
> صلوا علیه و آله

which means:

> His perfection procured exaltation
>
> His beauty dispelled the darkness
>
> All his attributes were good ones
>
> Pray for him, and for his family

The third one is [surah of Yasin](https://quran.com/36)

Comment: Is that some kinds of black magic? what is the purpose of this?

Comment: This answer is not complete and gives an incorrect impression, in the first picture you may read names of the 12 shi'a imams and the offspring of Fatima and 'Ali (like 'Ali Zayn al-'Abidyn). The middle finger however has the name of Fatima where the respectful expression (may Allah be pleased with her) is added on the fingertip and on the thumb the names of the four righteous caliphs withe which are beside the name of our prophet pbuh. I wonder how you could read surat yassin the text is mostly unreadable to me.